# Access a specific index in an array of arrays (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

I'm using python and have the following dictionary:

```
{
    'Measurement1': {
        'point1': [['1.1', '1,2', '497.1937349917', '497.1937349917', '497.1937349917'],
                   ['3.1', '1,2', '497.6760940676', '497.6760940676', '497.6760940676'],
                   ['1.1', '3,4', '495.0455154634', '495.0455154634', '495.0455154634'],
                   ['3.1', '3,4', '497.003633083', '497.003633083', '497.003633083']]
    }
}
```

I am trying to get all the elements from data['Measurement1']['point1'][*all_data_sets*][2] to do a ','.join() for additional calculations later in the program.  I'm hoping to get an output like:

```
'497.1937349917', '495.0455154634', '500.9453006597', '490.1952705428'
```

I'm currently looping through the array.

```
value_temp = []
for data_elem in data['Measurement1']['point1']:
    value_temp.append(data_elem[2])

output = ','.join(value_temp)
```

Is there a way to grab these values without performing the loop?

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: This is actually more a topic for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might be able to see a slight speed increase with a list comprehension `output=','.join([data_elem[2] for data_elem in data['Measurement1']['point1']])`.  You can't beat `O(n)` for this though (think of it this way: to write each element to the string, you have to look at it.  There's no way to "skip elements")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a more efficient way, you should use `numpy` for your whole project.

Just take your snippet as an example:

```
import numpy as np

# suppose your dict named "data"

data["Measurement1"]["point1"] = np.array(data["Measurement1"]["point1"])

output = ",".join(data["Measurement1"]["point1"][:, 2])
```

The indexing and calculation in `numpy` is done by `C`, so it is really much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after list comprehension (which is still essentially looping through, but in a more pythonic way):

```
",".join([data_elem[2] for data_elem in data['Measurement1']['point1']])
```

although the output values don't match what is actually in your post. If this is not what you want, please clarify where the values should come from...

Answer (score 1):

Given your original dict(dict(list(list()))),

```
x = {
  'Measurement1': {
    'point1': [['1.1', '1,2', '497.1937349917', '497.1937349917', '497.1937349917'],
               ['3.1', '1,2', '497.6760940676', '497.6760940676', '497.6760940676'],
               ['1.1', '3,4', '495.0455154634', '495.0455154634', '495.0455154634'],
               ['3.1', '3,4', '497.003633083', '497.003633083', '497.003633083']]
  }
}
```

Note that x['Measurement1']['point1'][2] is the ordinal 3rd (sub)array element. You can print this reference,

```
print (x['Measurement1']['point1'][2])
```

So, you could assign directly, use a list comprehension to reference, or simply join the elements of that (sub)array,

```
#use the (sub)array reference directly
','.join( x['Measurement1']['point1'][2] )
#or compose a new array using list comprehension
','.join( [ z for z in x['Measurement1']['point1'][2] ] )
#or assign array reference to variable
y = x['Measurement1']['point1'][2]
','.join( y )
```

You can also make a copy (to avoid accidental modification of original original,

```
#duplicate via list comprehension,
y = [ z for z in x['Measurement1']['point1'][2] ]
#copy the reference using list()
y = list( x['Measurement1']['point1'][2] )
#or copy.copy() #import copy
y = copy.copy( x['Measurement1']['point1'][2] )
#then
','.join( y )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the map function.

```
output = ",".join(map(lambda arr: arr[2],data['Measurement1']['point1']))
```